# DNEG xStudio Build unable to install packages

Tags: python, chocolatey

I'm currently trying to install DNEG's xStudio video review tool on Windows.
However, at step 4 [here](https://github.com/mpkepic/xstudio/blob/windows/docs/build_guides/windows.md), I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\Users\admin>choco install powershell-core -y
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
powershell-core
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'python 3.12.1 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.1)'
Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension' that is compatible with 'KB2999226 1.0.20181019 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.2)', 'KB3033929 1.0.5 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.4)', 'KB3035131 1.0.3 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.4)'.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - powershell-core - Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension' that is compatible with 'KB2999226 1.0.20181019 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.2)', 'KB3033929 1.0.5 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.4)', 'KB3035131 1.0.3 constraint: chocolatey-windowsupdate.extension (>= 1.0.4)'.

C:\Users\admin>choco install git -y
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
git
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'python 3.12.1 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.1)'
Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-core.extension' that is compatible with 'git.install 2.43.0 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.3)', 'vcredist140 14.38.33130 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.3)'.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - git - Unable to resolve dependency: Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey-core.extension' that is compatible with 'git.install 2.43.0 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.3)', 'vcredist140 14.38.33130 constraint: chocolatey-core.extension (>= 1.3.3)'.

C:\Users\admin>choco install cmake -y
Chocolatey v2.2.2
Installing the following packages:
cmake
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.
[NuGet] One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the Chocolatey lib folder. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'python 3.12.1 constraint: python3 (= 3.12.1)'
Unable to resolve dependency 'chocolatey': Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey' that is compatible with 'cmake.install 3.27.9 constraint: chocolatey (>= 0.10.5)'.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - cmake - Unable to resolve dependency 'chocolatey': Unable to find a version of 'chocolatey' that is compatible with 'cmake.install 3.27.9 constraint: chocolatey (>= 0.10.5)'.
```

It looks like it may be a python error. This is running in the administrative shell. How would I resolve these three packages?

Comment: The error is in the text. This is also answered in the documentation - https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/troubleshooting/dependency-troubles

Comment: missed that, many thanks for the pointer!

Comment: hm, unfortunately that workflow isn't working. the versions are installed and up to date, but chocolatey doesn't seem able to locate python. will update with any progress

Comment: turned out to be a firewall problem, disabling allowed the downloads to go through